# Alter table add column and set value

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have table in mysql, it's sutructure:

```
ID|    text|    content
1 |     bla|     sadas|
2 |     bla|     sadas|
3 |     bla|     sadas|
4 |     bla|     sadas|
```

I want to add new column "UID" with "alter table" and set ID's value to UID.

I added a new column but I dont know how I can set ID's value to UID with alter.

```
UID|    ID|    text|    content
 1 |    1 |     bla|     sadas|
 2 |    2 |     bla|     sadas|
 3 |    3 |     bla|     sadas|
 4 |    4 |     bla|     sadas|
```

Sorry, if I have written something wrong in the question, my english not good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update your_table
set uid = id
```